# Flutter: Using Hero without Navigation

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an app that uses a BottomNavigationBar to switch between two screens with their own navigation stack. I would like to use the Hero tag to create a custom transition between the two, but since I don't use navigation, but rather change the state to switch between screens, I'm not sure if this is possible at all.

Is there any way to recreate the transitions provided by Hero without using Navigator?

Answer (score 1):

The Hero widget is not what you are looking for. Try the `animations` package made by the flutter team. [Here](https://pub.dev/packages/animations) the link to this package.
Is not easy to use, but get a try, or you can use the default Navigation built in.